# How can I remove query params in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I have too many queries and url goes like this `/projects/1/&category=Branding&title=Mobile+App&about=Lorem+ipsum+Lorem+` and its longer than this!.

I just want to redirect like this `/projects/1/mobile-app` . I been trying to fix this for a week. I found couple solutions but they were with router.push and I'm using Link in a map. Someone told me to use as={} after the Link that works but page gives an error after the refresh.

**projects.tsx**

```
mport { AddProject } from "../../data/projects/AddProject";
import { projectsData } from "./../../types/types";

const Projects = () => {
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState<number>(4);
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState<string>("All");
    
  function getFilteredList() {
    if (activeMenu === "All") {
      return AddProject;
    }
    return AddProject.filter((project) => project.category === activeMenu);
  }

  const showMoreItems = () => {
    setLoadMore((prevValue) => prevValue + 4);
  };

  const filteredList = useMemo(getFilteredList, [activeMenu]);
   {filteredList.slice(0, loadMore).map((project: projectsData) => (
            <Link
              key={project.id}
              href={{
                pathname: "/projects/" + project.id,
                query: {
                  id: project.id,
                  category: project.category,
                  title: project.title,
                  about: project.aboutproject,
                  company: project.company,
                  client: project.client,
                  date: project.date,
                  website: project.website,
                  image: project.image.src,
                  image1: project.image1.src,
                  image2: project.image2.src,
                  image3: project.image3.src,
                  image4: project.image4.src,
                  image5: project.image5.src,
                },
              }}
              passHref={true}
            >
```

**[project].tsx**

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context: any) => {
  {
    const { query } = context;
    return { props: { query } };
  }
};

const Details = (props: any) => {
  const { query } = props;
  const [relatedPosts] = useState(AddProject);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<any>(0);

  const getResult = () => {
 
    return relatedPosts.filter(
      (related) => related.category === query.category
    );
  };

  var filteredList = useMemo(getResult, [query.category, relatedPosts]);

  const current = filteredList[index];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="single__page">
        <div className="down__arrow">
          <Links
            activeClass="down__arrow"
            to="about__project"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={500}
          >
            <CustomIcons name="DownArrow" />
          </Links>
        </div>
        <div className="single__header">
          <h2>{query.title}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: _"as={} after the Link that works but page gives an error after the refresh"_ - you'll have to persist the state of the query params on the client-side (like in `localStorage` for instance) if you want to completely hide the query params from the URL.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve your problem.

1. Either you can persist the state of the query params on the client side like in localStorage, this way you can avoid showing the query on the URL.

But the problem with this approach would be, you can't access localStorage in Next.js Data fetching method like **Server-side Rendering** or **Static Generation**

2. Create an onClick Handler that accepts the query parameter as a function argument, with the help of router.push() you can navigate to another page without showing query-params in the URL.

**project.js**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import CustomIcons from "../svg/CustomIcons";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import { AddProject } from "../../data/projects/AddProject";
import { projectsData } from "./../../types/types";

const Projects = () => {
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState < number > 4;
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState < string > "All";

  const router = useRouter();

  function onClickHandler(project) {
    console.log("clicked/");
    router.push(
      {
        pathname: "/about",
        query: {
          id: project.id,
          category: project.category,
          title: project.title,
          about: project.aboutproject,
          company: project.company,
          client: project.client,
          date: project.date,
          website: project.website,
          image: project.image.src,
          image1: project.image1.src,
          image2: project.image2.src,
          image3: project.image3.src,
          image4: project.image4.src,
          image5: project.image5.src
        }
      },
      "/about"
    );
  }
  function getFilteredList() {
    if (activeMenu === "All") {
      return AddProject;
    }
    return AddProject.filter((project) => project.category === activeMenu);
  }

  const showMoreItems = () => {
    setLoadMore((prevValue) => prevValue + 4);
  };

  const filteredList = useMemo(getFilteredList, [activeMenu]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="projects_category">
        <ul>
          <li
            className={activeMenu == "All" ? "activemenu" : ""}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu("All");
            }}
          >
            All
          </li>
          <li
            className={activeMenu == "Branding" ? "activemenu" : ""}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu("Branding");
            }}
          >
            Branding
          </li>
          <li
            className={activeMenu == "Design" ? "activemenu" : ""}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu("Design");
            }}
          >
            Design
          </li>
          <li
            className={activeMenu == "Photography" ? "activemenu" : ""}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu("Photography");
            }}
          >
            Photography
          </li>
          <li
            className={activeMenu == "Marketing" ? "activemenu" : ""}
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu("Marketing");
            }}
          >
            Marketing
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div className="projects">
        <div className="projects__inside">
          <div className="projects__vector">
            <CustomIcons name="ProjectsVector" />
          </div>

          {filteredList.slice(0, loadMore).map((project: projectsData) => (
            <button
              key={project.id}
              onClick={()=>onClickHandler(project)}
            >
              <section className="project__item">
                <div className="project__image">
                  <Image
                    src={project.image.src}
                    height={620}
                    width={520}
                    alt="project"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="project_info">
                  <h5>{project.category}</h5>
                  <h3>{project.title}</h3>
                </div>
              </section>
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="load__more">
          <div className="load__icon" onClick={showMoreItems}>
            <CustomIcons name="LoadMore" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Comment: Wrong answer, it's same as Link..... and for nextjs11, using useSearchParams instead, not work for hiding urls.